# Deserializing attributes of same name but different types in Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, jackson2

I have a REST API which returns a JSON response as:

```
{
    "channel" : "JHBHS"
}
```

and sometimes it returns:

```
{
    "channel": {
                    "id": 12321,
                    "name": "Some channel"
               }
}
```

I have a POJO like:

```
public class Event {
    private String channel;
    @JsonProperty("channel")
    private Channel channelObj;
}

public class Channel {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

So, is there a way (other than writing your own **custom deserializer**) in [Jackson2](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonRelease20) which will help me map `channel` in JSON to `String` type when it's a `String` and `Channel` type when it's a JSON Object?

Or in other words, is there a way in Jackson which maps by `type` of the variable and not just by `name`?

Comment: I found another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790727/providing-jackson-mapper-multiple-ways-to-deserialize-the-same-object

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can suggest you to use [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) like this:

```
class Event {

    @JsonProperty("channel")
    private JsonNode channelInternal;

    private Channel channel;

    private String channelStr;

    /**
     * Custom getter with channel parsing
     * @return channel
     */
    public Channel getChannel() {
        if (channel == null && channelInternal != null) {
            if (channelInternal.isObject()) {
                int id = channelInternal.get("id").intValue();
                String name = channelInternal.get("name").asText();
                channel = new Channel(id, name);
            }
        }
        return channel;
    }

    /**
     * Custom getter with channel string parsing
     * @return channel string
     */
    public String getChannelStr() {
        if (channelStr == null && channelInternal != null) {
            if (channelInternal.isTextual()) {
                channelStr = channelInternal.asText();
            }
        }
        return channelStr;
    }
}
```

**or like this**:

```
class Event {

    private Channel channel;

    private String channelStr;

    @JsonSetter("channel")
    public void setChannelInternal(JsonNode channelInternal) {
        if (channelInternal != null) {
            if (channelInternal.isTextual()) {
                channelStr = channelInternal.asText();
            } else if (channelInternal.isObject()) {
                int id = channelInternal.get("id").intValue();
                String name = channelInternal.get("name").asText();
                channel = new Channel(id, name);
            }
        }
    }

    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public String getChannelStr() {
        return channelStr;
    }
}
```

But I think using custom deserializer is more common.

Here is test code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String source1 = "{\n" +
            "    \"channel\" : \"JHBHS\"\n" +
            "}";
    String source2 = "{\n" +
            "    \"channel\": {\n" +
            "                    \"id\": 12321,\n" +
            "                    \"name\": \"Some channel\"\n" +
            "               }\n" +
            "}";

    //Test object parsing
    Event result = objectMapper.readValue(source2, Event.class);
    System.out.println(String.format("%s : %s", result.getChannel().getId(), result.getChannel().getName()));

    //Test string parsing
    result = objectMapper.readValue(source1, Event.class);
    System.out.println(result.getChannelStr());
}
```

And the output:

```
12321 : Some channel
JHBHS
```

Comment: Very detailed answer. But wouldn't a custom setter method do the job here like in this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27068928/1385441 ?

Comment: @Ramswaroop, just updated answer with second variant as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790727/providing-jackson-mapper-multiple-ways-to-deserialize-the-same-object/27068928#27068928