# How to fix "Conflicting getter definitions for property" error in FasterXml Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, fasterxml

I want to deserialize below xml string into a Java object , but I get the error 
    `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "service"`

This is XML string for deserialize:

```
<result>
<service>service_id</service>
<date>2019-01-30 12:10:33</date>
<status>0</status>
<service>
  <id>123</id>
  <name>name</name>
  <type>90</type>
</service>
</result>
```

This is POJO objects:

```
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "result")
public class CustomResult {

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "service")
   private String service;

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "date")
   private String date;

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "status")
   private Integer status;

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "service")
   private Service statusObj;

}

@Data
public class Service {

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id")
   private Integer id;

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
   private String name;

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "type")
   private Integer type;
}
```

and my converter code:

```
try {
       CustomResult result = new XmlMapper().readValue(xmlString, CustomResult.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I think this error occurs because the same name is two parameters. I get this xml from the server using the rest request and the parameter name cannot be changed. How to i fix this bug ?

Comment: SYou can not have two tags with equals name in an XML. rename one of them for instance: `<serviceid>service_id</serviceid>`

Comment: I do not have access to the server. Server developers do not want to fix xml

Comment: I was helped by the second method of response from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812973/deserializing-attributes-of-same-name-but-different-types-in-jackson

Answer (score 2):

First, your xml is valid.

Because I am not that familiar with jackson my first attempt was to read the file with [MOXy](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/). And this worked like scharm without any hassle.

```
@Test
public void xml() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    String xml = "<result>\n" +
            "<service>service_id</service>\n" +
            "<date>2019-01-30 12:10:33</date>\n" +
            "<status>0</status>\n" +
            "<service>\n" +
            "  <id>123</id>\n" +
            "  <name>name</name>\n" +
            "  <type>90</type>\n" +
            "</service>\n" +
            "</result>";

    try (ByteArrayInputStream baoust = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())) {
        CustomResult result = unmarshal(baoust, CustomResult.class);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

public <T> T unmarshal(final InputStream in, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    final Unmarshaller m = createUnmarshaller(clazz);
    return m.unmarshal(new StreamSource(in), clazz).getValue();
}

private <T> Unmarshaller createUnmarshaller(Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException, PropertyException {
    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    if (! (context instanceof org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext)) {
        throw new MissingResourceException("Missing MOXy implementation.",
                "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext", "");
    }
    final Unmarshaller m = context.createUnmarshaller();
    m.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    m.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.BEAN_VALIDATION_MODE, BeanValidationMode.NONE);
    return m;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
public static class CustomResult {

    public CustomResult() {}

   @XmlElement(name = "service")
   private String service;

   @XmlElement(name = "date")
   private String date;

   @XmlElement(name = "status")
   private Integer status;

   @XmlElement(name = "service")
   private Service statusObj;

}

@XmlType
public static class Service {

    public Service() {}

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
   private Integer id;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
   private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "type")
   private Integer type;
}
```

After this worked I was confident that it will be possible with Jackson, too.

```
@Test
public void xml() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    String xml = "<result>\n" +
            "<service>service_id</service>\n" +
            "<date>2019-01-30 12:10:33</date>\n" +
            "<status>0</status>\n" +
            "<service>\n" +
            "  <id>123</id>\n" +
            "  <name>name</name>\n" +
            "  <type>90</type>\n" +
            "</service>\n" +
            "</result>";

    CustomResult result2 = unmarshal(xml, CustomResult.class);
    System.out.println(result2);
}

public <T> T unmarshal(final String input, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    return xmlMapper.readValue(input, clazz);
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
public static class CustomResult {

   public CustomResult() {}

   @JsonIgnore
   private List<Object> service = new ArrayList<>();

   @XmlElement(name = "date")
   private String date;

   @XmlElement(name = "status")
   private Integer status;

   @JsonAnySetter
   public void setServices(String name, Object value) {
       if (value instanceof String) {
           service.add(value);
       }
       if (value instanceof Map) {
           // TODO create new Service object from map entries.
       }
       // error?
   }
}

@XmlType
public static class Service {

    public Service() {}

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
   private Integer id;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
   private String name;

    @XmlElement(name = "type")
   private Integer type;
}
```

I hope this helps you further.

Comment: in the method `unmarshal(final String input, Class<T> clazz)`  on the line `return xmlMapper.readValue(input, clazz);`  throw exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "service"...

Comment: @avazbek What version of jackson are you using? I used 2.9.7. I just copied code from above and the test run without exception.

Comment: I used jackson version 2.9.6

Comment: I was helped by the second method of response from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812973/deserializing-attributes-of-same-name-but-different-types-in-jackson