# Jackson - Deserializing after changing the data type of a class

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

I am making a data type change to an existing class A which is consumed by another client. Any changes to classA that are not updated on the client side will cause deserialization failures on the client side as its an incompatible change

ex:

```
public class classA {
    String id;
    List<String> names;
}
```

Changing `names` to the following will cause failures on the client side when deserializing as client will look for `List<String> names`

```
public class classA {
    String id;
    Map<String, List<String>> names;

}
```

What is the best practice to handle incompatible changes like these? I have referred a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812973/deserializing-attributes-of-same-name-but-different-types-in-jackson). Is there any cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: You should continue to provide `List<String> names` and provide the `Map` under a different name -- the question you linked to discusses deserialising and assumes that you can change the consumer of the data.

Comment: Are you asking how to handle both `List<String>` and `Map<String, List<String>>` in the client consuming the JSON ?

Comment: I basically want to know how can the migration from `List<String>` to `Map<String. List<String>>`happen without breaking the client

Comment: If you can't change the client, you'll have to keep providing the data it expects.